# AWS EMR setup auto termination policy issue

Tags: amazon-emr

Could not setup EMR auto termination idle time

AWS SDK 2.21.5 newest version,
I sent job to AWS EMR.
In AWS console, shows below, the idle time was correct, but the termination option is still
`Automatically terminate cluster after last step ends`
Click Edit button, you can that the radio button is on `terminate cluster after idle time`
Where is missing step? Why AWS thought I setup option 2, not option 3?

[image]

[image]

```
RunJobFlowRequest
            .builder()
            .autoTerminationPolicy(
              AutoTerminationPolicy
                  .builder()
                  .idleTimeout(300)
                  .build()
            )
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the answer myself, `keepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` should be true.

```
JobFlowInstancesConfig
  .builder()
  .keepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
```